# How to get form field from iframe using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2

I'm using fancybox 2 to open an iframe that displays some inputs as checkbox like:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="contact" name="sector" value="cellular">
```

now I want that when the user clicks on the fancybox title a parent function will be called with the all checkbox values.

this is my fancybox title:

```
'<li onclick="parent.sendIframeDataToParent(document.getElementByType("checkbox"), "sector_hook");">Submit</li>'
```

and I'm getting this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"` in your JavaScript terminates the HTML attribute you delimit with `"`. Giving you:

```
onclick="parent.sendIframeDataToParent(document.getElementByType("
```

When you have `"` as data in an attribute value delimited with `"`, represent them as `&quot;`.

Comment: sendIframeDataToParent gets 2 arguments:
the checkbox values and a string sector_hook

do you mind help me format the title string?

Comment: i cant get the input values from the form in the iframe